# Visual flicker when resizing image in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a simple JS animation of an image changing in size to 3 decimal places, and it is causing an annoying flickering effect on certain parts of the image. I find certain images create this effect others do not.

I am wondering how to animators fix this problem to remove the visual effect especially in Javascript.

You will need to see the effect on the JSFiddle. I created the animation here to see the visual effect on the buildings:
**http://jsfiddle.net/qerwsn07/**

```
function draw() {
    debug.innerHTML = 'Scale: '+scale;
    if(!dir){ 
        scale += 0.001; 
        if(scale > 1.09){ 
            dir = true;
        }
    } else if(dir) {
        scale -= 0.001;
        if(scale < 1){
            dir = false;   
        }
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, element.width, element.height);
    ctx.save()
    ctx.translate(element.width/2 - (camera.x / 500),element.height/2 - (camera.y / 500));      
    var x       =  - ((img.width * scale) / 2);
    var y       =  - ((img.height* scale) / 2);
    var width   = img.width * scale;
    var height  = img.height*scale;

    ctx.drawImage(img,x,y,img.width*scale,img.height*scale);
    ctx.restore();
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
draw();
```

Are there ways to remove or reduce the effect at all ?

Comment: Are you calling `draw()` on `window.on('resize`);`?

Comment: No. Did you see the fiddle?

Comment: Woops sorry. Was that part of an edit? :P Is there any reason you're not utilizing css for this? Happy to provide an example of that that would get you around this issue if you're open to plain css.

Comment: @Dave I have just tried this in Chrome and IE and i have no flickering at all even when resizing the browser. is there anything else you maybe doing? Have you tried `img.onload = function () {
    draw();
}`

Comment: @RobErskine it's to do with canvas animations so CSS is not an option here.

Comment: @Canvas I am not re-sizing the browser at all. And it seems to be only effecting some people but not all. For reason's i am unsure, not all images do it and not everyone experiences the visual effect. Try different images if you can.

Comment: Only reason I ask is because your example could be done with just a plain background image. Maybe the source you're omitting is causing the flickering issue then?

Comment: @RobErskine yeah but this is a problem that is occurring in my overall large canvas project :P I just singled out the bug (if you can call it a bug) to as little code as possible to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Dave I have just tried like 10+ different images of all shapes and formats and I still don't seem to be having an issue, can you at all find anymore information on how to get it to flicker?

Comment: @Canvas I don't fully know the cause, on the original image on the buildings you can see this strange pattern emerging when you zoom in and out. I believe it might be related to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern

Comment: @Dave at about 1.3 to 1.5 I can see some sort of odd drawing effected on the image, is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Yeah i believe you might be seeing what I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I can not see this on the machine I am on now, I know what your problem is. There are two ways to reduce it.

First the problem is caused by pixel sampling. When an image is scaled there is no longer a one to one match between the screen pixels (physical pixels on the devices display) and the pixels in the image. When you zoom out (make the image smaller) there are more pixels in the image than can be displayed. When you zoom in (make the image larger) pixels spread over more than one.

The most basic solution is called nearest pixel sampling. The hardware calculates  where on the scaled image each device display pixels then selects the nearest pixel to that point in the image.

The most common alternative is bilinear interpolation. In this method the hardware uses the nearest 4 pixels when zooming in (make image larger) and calculates the colour by a simple linear interpolation between the left and right, then top and bottom and displaying the average colour. When zooming out it averages the pixels that are under the display pixel. This method reduces flicker a lot but does not eliminate it altogether.

The canvas lets you select between nearest pixel, and the smoothing mode of the hardware. What is used to smooth is dependent on the hardware configuration.

To use the smoothing method set the `imageSmoothingEnabled` property of the 2D context to `true`

```
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
```

To turn it off

```
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

But by default this is "true" for the canvas. So I do not think this will fix your problem right away.

If you are using a PC your graphics driver may have come with a utility to adjust rendering performance. These utilities can usually be found in the windows control panel. Depending on the hardware and what drivers you are using the options will vary. Usually they have a performance panel, where you can set up the hardware for performance, or quality. The performance setting will over ride the canvas smoothing option and only use nearest pixel (or whatever the device is quickest at). If you have that set it to best quality, and see if that changes the flicker.

Also some of these utilities let you set the quality setting per application. So check that the graphics device has that option and if the browser is on the list. If it is then change it to best quality.

Some drivers let you set individual graphics options. So have a look and change pixel filtering to that which suits you. You may have to force the browser to use it by setting pixel filtering on as an application setting.
(If you are using a Mac consult the help)

If everything is set correctly but the flickering that remains is bothering you then you will have to use other methods to reduce the problem.

**Image blur;**

For use when zooming out. A modification of Mip-mapping. You need to create a second copy of the image in memory and blur that image slightly. When you zoom out render the blurred image. You may also want to have a small transition  between the blurred image and the original to stop it being noticed as the scale switched from zoomed in to zoomed out. This can be done by using `ctx.globalAlpha` to fade one image over the other.

**Mip mapping;**

This method involves creating many copies of the image. Each one at half the the resolution of the one before it. You will have to use a good down sampler (photoshop, Gimp, Paint.net) all have downsampling options. Or you can write one yourself and do it in code.

When displaying the image zoomed out you draw the two images that are closest the the zoomed size with a fade between the two dependent on how close the zoom is to the downsampled image side.

No matter what you do you will still always have some artifacts when zooming. Each method has its advantages and disadvantages. For the best quality you start with an image that is twice the resolution in pixels of the largest zoom. You then sample the image in code with your prefered sampling method when rendering (Javascript is not up to that job with 2D context, you need to use the GPU and webGL)

**EDIT added test for browser smoothing**

I have added a small test to see if smoothing is being overwritten by the graphics device driver on your machine. Left test pattern has smoothing off the other has smoothing on. If both look the same then the browser is not in control of smoothing.

```js
// this code is not intended as an answer but as a way of checking 
// device smoothing is avalible or not.
var canvas = document.getElementById("canV");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// not commented as not a code answer.
var currentSurface = ctx;
var createImage = function (w, h) {
    var image = document.createElement("canvas");  
    image.width = w;
    image.height = h !== undefined?h:w; 
    currentSurface = image.ctx = image.getContext("2d"); 
    return image;
}  


var img = createImage(256,256);
var imageDat = img.ctx.getImageData(0,0,255,255);
var dat = imageDat.data;
var ind = 0;
var lines = 2;
var grow = 2;
var black = 0
var white = 255
for(var y = 0; y < 256; y++){
    for(var x = 0; x < 256; x++){
        if(x%lines < lines-1){
            dat[ind++] = black;
            dat[ind++] = black;
            dat[ind++] = black;
        }else{
            dat[ind++] = white;
            dat[ind++] = white;
            dat[ind++] = white;
        }
        dat[ind++] = 255;
    }
    if(y%lines < lines-1){
        black = 0;
        white = 255;
    }else{
        black = 255;
        white = 0;
    }
    grow += 0.04;
    lines = Math.floor(grow);
}
img.ctx.putImageData(imageDat,0,0);
var count = 1000;
var tick = 0;
function update(){
    tick += 0.01;
    zoom = Math.sin(tick)*64;
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctx.drawImage(img,64-zoom,64-zoom,zoom*2+128,zoom*2+128,0,0,200,200)
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
    ctx.drawImage(img,64-zoom,64-zoom,zoom*2+128,zoom*2+128,205,0,200,200)
    
    requestAnimationFrame(update)
}
update();
```

```css
#canV {
  width:405px;
  height:200px;
}
.smallText {
  font-size:small;  
}
b {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="smallText">Image on the left is <b>ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;</b> and image on the right is <b>ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;</b>. If they both look the same then the divice driver is overwriting the browser smoothing.</div>
<canvas id="canV" width=405 height=200></canvas>
```

Comment: This is good answer actually, the problem with the solutions are with mip mapping the zoom is only fractional amount, it just so happens this fractional amount causes the problem. And the blur method might ruin the visual of the canvas animation, i'm not 100% sure how to do image blur in canvas =/ How do games manage to solve this given they must zoom and out of 2D textures a lot ?

Comment: I assume you have seen the demo code I provides and you see a difference between the two image, indicating that your smoothing is functioning correctly. There's not much that can be done apart from avoiding high contrast pixel boundaries where the width of the opposing bright pixels is smaller than the zoom. ie 1 pix wide white on black will flicker as soon as you zoom out, while 2pixs wide will not until you zoom out to near half original size. So don't blur all the image just the bits that flicker, or widen the area off those pixels that flicker out.

Comment: Hmm okay, I'll try it. I'll also look into blur to see if that can help. I noticed 3D games don't have this issue - unless they just avoid those types of textures. And yes the demo - one is much better than the other for sure.

Comment: 3d Games do have the problem and a lot of time is spent making sure images are not susceptible. Also 3D and webGL have direct access to the shaders and a host of different smoothing techniques that the 2D canvas can not access. If you find the flicker is unacceptable then you should look into using webGL to render to the canvas. More work in terms of code, less browser support ( though getting better), but higher quality results, and much greater render speeds.